# WHERE statement SQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm new to SQL and PHP, so my knowledge is not enough to fix it.

I want to have a `WHERE` statement in my long query, but it is not working...

```
$db->fetch_object_array("SELECT rooms.*, landing_page.url, config_file.config_name,projects.project_name, room_users.hostcode, room_users.guestcode, room_users.first_name, room_users.last_name, 
                   room_users.active, room_users.configuration, config_active, room_users.user_id, rooms.config_id, room_users.trained, license.id AS licenseid
                FROM slots
            LEFT JOIN rooms
              ON rooms.room_id = slots.room_id
            LEFT JOIN room_users
              ON room_users.room_id = rooms.room_id
            LEFT JOIN config_file
              ON config_file.config_id = rooms.config_id
            LEFT JOIN license
              ON license.id = slots.license_id
            LEFT JOIN projects
              ON license.project_id = rooms.project_id
            LEFT JOIN landing_page
              ON landing_page.project_id = license.project_id
            WHERE slots.license_id IN (SELECT id FROM license WHERE id = '{$_GET['license']}' OR parent_id = '{$_GET['license']}')
            GROUP BY rooms.room_id
            ORDER BY slots.license_id ASC, rooms.room_name ASC");
```

I want to have `rooms_config_active` to be configured to the `GET variable` `"filtering"` but its not working.

My get variable:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='get'><select id="selectActive" name='filtering'>
                <option value="">Please select a option</option>
                <option value="active">Active</option>
                <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
            </select>Active / Inactive    <input type='submit' name='filter' value="filter"></th>
        </form>
```

So how can I make this work with my filtering get variable? I want to have it afterwards `rooms.config_active` or `config_active`

thanks in advance guys!

Anything similiar like this:

```
WHERE config_active = $filterting
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What's not working ? Also, your SQL is wide open to injections.

Comment: That doesn't matter right now.. I want to query the rooms.config_active with 1, but I don't know where to put it..

Comment: query seems to be good, better check application side validations and data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where clause

```
WHERE 
slots.license_id IN 
(
SELECT id FROM license WHERE id = '{$_GET['license']}' 
OR parent_id = '{$_GET['license']}'
)
```

does not make sense , you have already joined `license` table  so you may use the condition as

```
where
 ( 
  license.id = '{$_GET['license']}' 
  or license.parent_id = '{$_GET['license']}' 
)
```

Now adding the new filter it would be as

```
where
 ( 
   license.id = '{$_GET['license']}' 
   or license.parent_id = '{$_GET['license']}' 
 )
 and config_active = '{$_GET['filtering']}'
```

So the query becomes

```
SELECT 
rooms.*, 
landing_page.url, 
config_file.config_name,
projects.project_name, 
room_users.hostcode, 
room_users.guestcode, 
room_users.first_name, 
room_users.last_name, 
room_users.active, 
room_users.configuration, 
config_active, 
room_users.user_id, 
rooms.config_id, 
room_users.trained, 
license.id AS licenseid
FROM slots
LEFT JOIN rooms
ON rooms.room_id = slots.room_id
LEFT JOIN room_users
ON room_users.room_id = rooms.room_id
LEFT JOIN config_file
ON config_file.config_id = rooms.config_id
LEFT JOIN license
ON license.id = slots.license_id
LEFT JOIN projects
ON license.project_id = rooms.project_id
LEFT JOIN landing_page
ON landing_page.project_id = license.project_id
where
 ( 
  license.id = '{$_GET['license']}' 
  or license.parent_id = '{$_GET['license']}' 
 )
and config_active = '{$_GET['filtering']}'

GROUP BY rooms.room_id
ORDER BY slots.license_id ASC, rooms.room_name ASC
```

Comment: What can I do to add the query?

Comment: I have added the new query into the answer.

Comment: Remember left join with where clause will filter the data, so you need to make sure that data exists for these filtering condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use arrays in a string you have to use `".."` to get them in the string. just putting the `$_GET['license']` in there won't work.

```
$sql = "SELECT rooms.*, landing_page.url, config_file.config_name,projects.project_name, room_users.hostcode, room_users.guestcode, room_users.first_name, room_users.last_name, 
               room_users.active, room_users.configuration, config_active, room_users.user_id, rooms.config_id, room_users.trained, license.id AS licenseid
            FROM slots
        LEFT JOIN rooms
          ON rooms.room_id = slots.room_id
        LEFT JOIN room_users
          ON room_users.room_id = rooms.room_id
        LEFT JOIN config_file
          ON config_file.config_id = rooms.config_id
        LEFT JOIN license
          ON license.id = slots.license_id
        LEFT JOIN projects
          ON license.project_id = rooms.project_id
        LEFT JOIN landing_page
          ON landing_page.project_id = license.project_id
        WHERE slots.license_id IN (SELECT id FROM license WHERE id = '{".$_GET['license']."}' OR parent_id = '{".$_GET['license']."}')
        GROUP BY rooms.room_id
        ORDER BY slots.license_id ASC, rooms.room_name ASC";
$db->fetch_object_array($sql);
```

best thing to check for errors would be to `echo $sql` and check the statement in the db manualy.

Comment: How can I add my query then inside it?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand that question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it almost fixed..

```
SELECT rooms.*, landing_page.url, config_file.config_name,projects.project_name, room_users.hostcode, room_users.guestcode, room_users.first_name, room_users.last_name, rooms.config_active,
                   room_users.active, room_users.configuration, room_users.user_id, rooms.config_id, room_users.trained, license.id AS licenseid
                FROM slots
            LEFT JOIN rooms
              ON rooms.room_id = slots.room_id
            LEFT JOIN room_users
              ON room_users.room_id = rooms.room_id
            LEFT JOIN config_file
              ON config_file.config_id = rooms.config_id
            LEFT JOIN license
              ON license.id = slots.license_id
            LEFT JOIN projects
              ON license.project_id = rooms.project_id
            LEFT JOIN landing_page
              ON landing_page.project_id = license.project_id
            WHERE slots.license_id IN (SELECT id FROM license WHERE id = 6 OR parent_id = 6) AND rooms.config_active = 1 // or the variable :)
            GROUP BY rooms.room_id
            ORDER BY slots.license_id ASC, rooms.room_name ASC
```

Thanks for the support!

with the variable GET it is not working..
It is giving only inactive results/